# Reform Judaism as an avenue for Ethical Monotheism for gentiles

Tags: halacha, gentiles, reform-judaism, noahidism

If Orthodoxy and Halacha do not see the Reform movement as "valid", then is it fair to say that Reform Judaism is permissible for Gentiles to practice (assuming they have no Jewish ancestry matrilineally)?

Would this make them Righteous Gentiles as well, considering that they are using Reform Judaism to uphold monotheism and certain mitzvot, especially if they come from a place where idolatry is rampant (for example, India, Nepal, pagan cultures).

(I know that conversion is not required or necesarily encouraged by Orthodox ideals, but this question is more theoretical in nature.)

Comment: In short it is monotheistic, https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/reform_practices.html (See the section on fundemental principles)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin AFAIK they are monotheistic; although some might not believe that God plays an active role in the world.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The movement itself is monotheistic, but there are many Reform Jews who identify either as deistic, atheistic, or agnostic.

Comment: Gentiles already have the 7 laws of Noah and would not benefit from a distorted version of Judaism as the reform movement does not accept the Torah which commands non Jews to keep the 7 laws of Noah.

Comment: We have Sheva Miztvot, but what we don't have is community for our children. Many of us are just meandering out here, on the edge of Rabbinic rejection. Pain, frustrating, self-doubt. What we in fact have is a vapid religious expression of Monotheism. I wonder if the same

Comment: We have Sheva Miztvot, but what we don't have is community for our children. Many of us are just meandering out here, on the edge of Rabbinic rejection. Pain, frustrating, self-doubt. What we in fact have is a vapid religious expression of Monotheism. I wonder if the same question was asked about the Conservative Movement, would the answer be a better one, FOR US, and our kids. In my city we have a Chabad House, where the Rabbi told me that we may not attend for ANY service unless we convert. Conversion is a whole other mess of double standards.

Comment: The Baal Teshuva can always return at whatever level he is, and grow into more and more observance. No exams, no hoops, just homecoming. Some noachides are such only because they aren't acceptable to the Rabbinical Court. The casualties are real, and some of us are just giving up, and going into greater error.

Comment: I am reminded of Mishneh Torah about talking to a potential convert, when it says, concerning punishment or consequences of missing certain mitzvot,  "... And they do not dwell at length on this, nor do they go into detail, lest this causes him to be troubled and turn away from the good path to the evil path. For at the beginning we do not draw a person except with words of appeasement andgentleness. I drew them with human ties, with cords of love." They don't seem to follow this idea well.

Comment: I found Noachidism to be vapid, and problematic for devout people. I wish I never entertained it at all! .... I guess ya had to be there to really get, what it's really like. A Monotheistic Exile, if you will.

Comment: @Tessa "A Monotheistic Exile" is a very good description of what it's like to be a Noahide. Really makes little difference to the many good people of the world, but for someone who loved Hashem and followed Him out of the religion of his fathers, it's a life of exile. Some of us are trying to fix that, but there are not enough of us. Blessings to those on the journey.

Answer (score 5):

The logic of the description in [The Tenets of Reform Judaism](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/reform_practices.html) cited by @ARK96 would seem to imply that it is not a valid source for Noachides. The reason would be that

> Reform Judaism differs from the other major movements in that it views both the Oral and Written laws as a product of human hands
>
> Reform Judaism demands that Jews confront the claims of Jewish tradition, however differently perceived, and exercise their individual autonomy
>
> The "Oral Law" is not seen as divinely given at Sinai, but rather as a reflection of Judaism's historic development and encounter with God in each succeeding generation.

As an example, Reform would allow anyone to keep Shabbos fully **if they want to** which is not allowed for a non-Jew.

A Noachide must believe that the Torah was given to the Jews by Hashem and the Noachide laws are **required** by Hashem as for example at [Must a non-Jew accept the Noachide laws as binding?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61545/must-a-non-jew-accept-the-noachide-laws-as-binding/61546#61546) or [Seven Laws of Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah)

> The Seven Laws of Noah (Hebrew: שבע מצוות בני נח‎ Sheva mitzvot B'nei
>   Noach), also referred to as the Noahide Laws or the Noachide Laws
>   (from the Hebrew transliteration of "Noah"), are a set of **imperatives**
>   that, according to the Talmud, were given by God[1] as a **binding set
>   of laws** for the "children of Noah" – that is, all of humanity.[2][3]
>
> Accordingly, any non-Jew who adheres to these laws because they were
>   given by Moses[4] is regarded as a righteous gentile, and is assured
>   of a place in the world to come (Hebrew: עולם הבא‎ Olam Haba), the
>   final reward of the righteous.[5][6]
>
> 1. According to Encyclopedia Talmudit (Hebrew edition, Israel, 5741/1981, Entry Ben Noah, page 349), most medieval authorities
>      consider that all seven commandments were given to Adam, although
>      Maimonides (Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot M'lakhim 9:1) considers the dietary
>      law to have been given to Noah.
> 2. Encyclopedia Talmudit (Hebrew edition, Israel, 5741/1981, entry Ben Noah, introduction) states that after the giving of the Torah, the
>      Jewish people were no longer in the category of the sons of Noah;
>      however, Maimonides (Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot M'lakhim 9:1) indicates
>      that the seven laws are also part of the Torah, and the Talmud (Bavli,
>      Sanhedrin 59a, see also Tosafot ad. loc.) states that Jews are
>      obligated in all things that Gentiles are obligated in, albeit with
>      some differences in the details.3. Compare Genesis 9:4–6.
> 3. "Melachim uMilchamot 8:11". www.chabad.org. last two sentences of the three. Retrieved 2015-06-24.
>
> This applies only when he accepts them and fulfills them because the
>   Holy One, blessed be He, commanded them in the Torah and informed us
>   through Moses, our teacher, that Noah's descendants had been commanded
>   to fulfill them previously.
>
> However, if he fulfills them out of intellectual conviction, he is not
>   a resident alien, nor of 'the pious among the gentiles,' nor of their
>   wise men.
>
> 5. Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot M'lakhim 8:14
> 6. Encyclopedia Talmudit (Hebrew edition, Israel, 5741/1981, entry Ben Noah, end of article); note the variant reading of Maimonides and the
>      references in the footnote

[The Seven Noachide Laws](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/The_Seven_Noahide_Laws.html)

> The Noachide Laws are seven laws considered by rabbinic tradition as
>   the minimal moral duties required by the Bible on all men. While Jews
>   are obligated to observe the whole Torah - 613 commandments, every
>   non-Jew is considered a "son of the covenant of Noah" and he **who
>   accepts these obligations** is considered a righteous person who is
>   guaranteed a place in the world to come.

Comment: Where do we learn that a Noachide must believe that?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I added a couple of quick citations.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61545/1713

Comment: Accd to your proofs, why can't they think these 7 are commanded by God to Moses, but that Moses made up Shaatnez and really God intended only 612 commandments for Jews? Or better why can't they believe that God commanded 7 to Noah, and Moses and the Jews have nothing to do with God?

Comment: Thanks for adding support for that.  (I wasn't questioning the description of Reform, just the part about belief requirements for Noachides.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Tha is a totally different question. However (as you well know) other questions have dealt with the fact that once someone claims any of the 613 was made up by Moshe, than he is denying the entire Torah. In any event that issue is not relevant to the question. Also that is why I showed the quote that they must accept that the 7 came from Moshe.